# How can i render out the Nav component everywhere except the Login Page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

```
// MAIN FUNCTION { APP START }
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Nav /> 
      <Switch>
        <Route to="/" exact component={Home} />
        <Route to="/login" exact component={Login} />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I  just want that the Nav component renders everywhere except the login page  ??

Answer (score 0):

You can put it inside a route component along with the Home.

```
<Router> <Switch>
   <Route path="/" exact>
      <Nav />
      <Home />
   </Route>
   <Route to="/login" exact component={Login} />
</Switch> </Router>
```